# Delete Page PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys I have created A delete page, It does not work when I just submit the form and the URL is http://localhost/delete-session.php but once I change the URL to http://localhost/delete-session.php?id=1 it works, What am I missing In my code to make it work?

```
<h1>Delete Page</h1>

<h3>Enter the booking number of the session you would like to delete!</h3>
<form action ="delete-session.php" method="post">

Booking ID:(Refer To Database):<input type="text" name="booking">
```

This is the php

```
if(isset($_GET['booking'])){
    $id=$_GET['booking'];    
    if(!is_numeric($id)){
        echo "sorry, there appears to have been an error.";
        exit;
    }
} else {
    echo "sorry, there appears to have been an error.";
    exit;
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "olympics";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$id=$_GET['id'];
if(!is_numeric($id)){
    echo "Sorry, there is an error";
    exit;
}

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql="DELETE from olympiics where booking='$id'";
echo $sql;

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a crack at this.

I'm guessing it's because when you go to `http://localhost/delete-session.php?id=1` you're passing the `id=1` via GET, so when you retrieve the GET input from in your code it succeeds with `$id=1`, but in your HTML your form is send via POST.

As a fix try using `$id=$_POST['booking'];`

Answer (score 0):

Bench test your code.

It starts getting `$id=$_GET['booking'];` which does not exist because you have set the `method="post"` in your `<form>` tag.

So use `$id=$_POST['booking'];`

Then later on it does `$id=$_GET['id'];` overwriting the value you already attempted to get from above.

This would explain why it requires the extra id paramter on `http://localhost/delete-session.php?id=1` as using the querystring to send data will send the `id` parameter in the `$_GET['id']` array, and I dont see why you would want to do this anyway as it has been done at the top of your code by getting this id value from `$id=$_POST['booking']`

> It also makes code so much easier to read and **more importantly debug** if you adopt an indentation standard in your script like below.

Try this out for size, without adding the `id=1` to the querystring

```
if(isset($_POST['booking'])){
    $id=$_POST['booking'];    
    if(!is_numeric($id)){
        echo "sorry, there appears to have been an error. Booking must be numeric";
        exit;
    }
} else {
    echo "sorry, there appears to have been an error.";
    exit;
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "olympics";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql="DELETE from olympiics where booking='$id'";

$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($res !== FALSE) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

> As you are using the mysqli extension, you should also be using parameterized queries to prevent SQL Injection.

```
if(isset($_POST['booking'])){
    $id=$_POST['booking'];    
    if(!is_numeric($id)){
        echo "sorry, there appears to have been an error. Booking must be numeric";
        exit;
    }
} else {
    echo "sorry, there appears to have been an error.";
    exit;
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "olympics";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql="DELETE from olympiics where booking=?";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
if ( $stmt === FALSE ) {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
    exit;
}
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $id); 


$res = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if ($res !== FALSE) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much buddy you are a genuine life saver! How do I select this as an answer to help others?

Answer (score -1):

Change form method to get, or use $_REQUEST instead of $_GET